# Elements within a container doesn't take full width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am developing a theme in HTML5 using Bootstrap 3 and Css3 , whenever i put any element within a container, that element doesn't take full width and leaves the space by the margin of around 10 pixels from either side of the container. But i want to use full width of the container, what should i do ??

Comment: *wha should i do ??* **Contribute your code**

Comment: pardon, i Meant what should i do ?

Comment: Post your code over here so that users can debug

Comment: Let us know what have you tried with a code sample. It might be something as easy as negative margins on the first child element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation from Bootstrap notes that containers are not nestable. You should only have 1 container for the main part of the page. Within that container you can use divs, or other block elements, without overusing the container class.

> Easily center a page's contents by wrapping its contents in a .container. Containers set width at various media query breakpoints to match our grid system.
>
> Note that, due to padding and fixed widths, containers are not nestable by default.
>
> http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container

Comment: i have used 3 containers altogether, the header ( class="container"), a div (container for main contents) and the footer( class="container"). All of my containers are in the same line there isn't any issue for that.

Comment: As i am new to stack-overflow Can anyone tell me how to post HTML or any other code here ? I have tried with the  "{}" button but it doesn't work :( Can anyone help me out so that i can post my code and users can debug and find out the solution ?

Comment: You want to edit your original question. The "{}" button is the correct button to format as code. Read up on the Markdown formatting to understand the formatting better.